# How to properly cope with Memory residing Bitmap resize

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, resize

I have bitmap residing in memory (coming from my webcam but I don't think that this makes a difference.
It is 960x540 120dpi

[image]

you see that the picture in the lower part gets till the point where my shirt begins.

I know the bmp dimensions since I put this code prior resize

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\3.bmp", FileMode.Create))
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

and the result is the picture above.

Then I resize it with that:

```
var resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                width, height,           // Resized dimensions 200x112
                source.DpiX, source.DpiY,// Default DPI values
                PixelFormats.Default);   // Default pixel format
```

and the result is the bmp below which is properly 200x112 but it cuts out in part of the image in the lower and right part.

[image]

I have seen that the problem is related with the dpi value in the RenderTargetBitmap instruction. If I divide the dpi by 1.25 everything gets fine but why 1.25???????

Thank you in advance for any help
Patrick

--ADD--

There is something additional that I can't understand: I know the initial bitmap size for I have saved it to filesytem with the instructions above.
But if I look at the properties by putting a breakpoint I see:

BITMAP BEFORE RESIZE

> width,height = 768, 432
>
> pixelwidth, pixelheight = 960, 540
>
> dpiX, dpiY= 120, 120

BITMAP AFTER RESIZE

> width,height = 160, 89
>
> pixelwidth, pixelheight = 200, 112
>
> dpiX, dpiY= 120, 120

now I know that what counts here is pixelwidth, pixelheight so that's correct.

If I do 960/786 I get 1.25! So that's my number but why? Can I correct the code as to make it a general solution???

Comment: You haven't show the relevant part where you actually copy the source to the target bitmap. Anyway, it's not clear why you would use a RenderTargetBitmap at all. Why not simply use a TransformedBitmap with an appropriate ScaleTransform?

Comment: If you have a DPI setting of 120, the DIP(device-independent pixels) size is 1.25 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `RenderTargetBitmap` you should simply use a `TransformedBitmap` with an appropriate `ScaleTransform`:

```
var scale = 200d / 960d;
var resizedImage = new TransformedBitmap(source, new ScaleTransform(scale, scale));
```

Comment: The problem (which to you might not be a problem) is that  I need a BitmapImage (my source bitmap passed here by red) and not a TransformedBitmap so I get this error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TransformedBitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'

Comment: Sorry for the type not by red but by ref = by reference

Comment: You hardly ever really need a BitmapImage. Change the type of your property or method parameter or whatever to `BitmapSource`, which is the common base class of BitmapImage, TransformedBitmap and a lot of other specialized bitmap classes. For e.g. setting the `Source` property of an Image control you could even use `ImageSource`, the base class of BitmapSource.

Comment: That said, you would have the same problem with RenderTargetBitmap, which also is not derived from BitmapImage, but from BitmapSource.